# Why does a EF Core nullable entity cause "The expected type was 'System.String' but the actual value was null?"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6 and .NET 6, I have a many-to-one relationship between `Party` and `StatEntity`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Party>()
  .HasMany(p => p.PartyMembers)
  .WithOne(p => p.Party);
```

Where the `StatEntity` may not necessarily have a `Party`:

```
[NotLogged] [JsonIgnore] public Party? Party { get; set; }
```

Indeed, we can see that `PartyId` is configured as nullable based upon the auto generated migration:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "PartyId",
                table: "StatEntities",
                type: "varchar(36)",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "varchar(36)")
                .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "latin1")
                .OldAnnotation("MySql:CharSet", "latin1");
```

- According to `__EFMigrationsHistory`, the migration was successfully applied.
- There exist `null` values for `PartyId` in the database.

However, when I try to query a `StatEntity` that has a `null` value for `PartyId`, I receive the following:

> An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'StatEntity.PartyId'. The expected type was 'System.String' but the actual value was null.

Note that I am **not** attempting to `.Include(statEntity => statEntity.Party)`. It seems that EF Core is not allowing null values for the shadow property, even though it is declared as such.

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around, explicitly defining the shadow property on the `StatEntity` appears to fix the problem:

```
    [NotLogged] [JsonIgnore] public string? PartyId { get; set; }

    [NotLogged] [JsonIgnore] public FurballParty? Party { get; set; }
```

Curiously, running a `dotnet ef migrations add blah` creates an empty migration, so definitely nothing wrong with the database aspect. It appears to be a bug in EFCore that causes the underlying shadow property to not be correctly defined as nullable.

Comment: *It appears to be a bug* - you can report it to them; https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues